# iPad mini Keyboard issue with ios8.x version

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, uikeyboard, ios8.3

Sometime when I try to enter a text in textfield or textview , the key board comes up too large to fit on screen. so only part of the key board and keys are visible. I can turn the I pad sideways and make the missing keys visible, but then the keys won't work anyway. i have not done any keyboard customization in my app. I don't know whether it is an app issue or OS issue. Have you ever faced this type of issue?
Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Device:iPad mini
Model=iPad2,7
OS Version=8.4.

The accessibility settings are turned off on this iPAD. Customers have reported the app is crashing if they press any key after G , after keyboard is zoomed in like shown in the attached picture.

[image: Keyboard issue in iPad Mini- iOS 8.4]

Comment: It is unusual, can you attach screenshot of it?

Comment: Which iOS version are you running on that iPad mini? Be more specific

Comment: Here are the details:  Device:iPad mini  Model=iPad2,7  osVersion=8.4,

Comment: have you found a solution to this? I'm encountering a similar issue.